# How to call a function in Swift?

Tags: swift, function

I made a function that will give a random center to the x coordinate of a UIImageView:

```
func place(){

    var ran: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 500)
    Retry.center.x = ran

}
```

I want to call the function within the `viewDidLoad` function but It doesn't seem to work. I've tried `self.place()` and `[self place]` and just `place()` but none call the method. Im working on Xcode 7 with Swift Language.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but change `arc4random() % 500` to `arc4random_uniform(500)`.

Comment: Where did you write this function? Is it in a class?

Comment: This code works perfectly.  I tried it with an NSTimer so that every second it changes based on the "ran" value and it works.  But I need it to run on my command not a timer.  Thanks for that though. I'm not 100% sure how arc random works still. And this function is within the ViewController class.

Comment: Try that out : Go to your storyboard and click on the UIImageView you want to change(and i suppose you have in there the function). ctrl click drag from the UIImageView to the viewController.Name the outlet. call the method using the outletsName.place(). What does it show ?

Comment: I get an error saying Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'place' when I try to run 'Retry.place()'.  Retry is the name of the UIImageView. I had already made the outlet for it.

Comment: You haven't described the scope.  The function is defined but where? If you try to call it from another object you need to give that object visibility to the defining scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

To enable your code to send messages to a user interface object, create a connection from the user interface object to an outlet in your code. The easiest way is to control-drag from the object in Interface Builder to the implementation file in the assistant editor.After that you can use a property observer and have it like this in order for it to work[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var someView: theView!
        {
            didSet
            {
                someView.place()               
            }
```

sorry about the image being with objective c code but you get the point :)
Also as suggested do use `arc4random_uniform` instead of `arc4random() % 500`

Comment: It keeps saying 'UIImage' has no member 'place'

Comment: can you share a bit more code? if the function is in your UIImagrView it shouldn't say that

Answer (score 0):

You should make layout changes in viewDidLayoutSubviews by override this method and calling `place()` there.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    place()
}
```